# Choice of .Net technology for multiple access to one single USB-device

Tags: c#, usb

I have an application which currently have three modules/layers; a GUI, a layer of logic and calculations and a layer that provides access to the USB-device and it's data (below that there is the USB-driver but that isn't part of our source code). The USB-device is a resource that can be used by only one software instance at a time.

This have been working fine but now we want to enable the user to run multiple instances of the application towards the same USB-device. So now we will have to share the lowest layer (access to USB-device) between software instances (as the USB-driver can't be shared). You can see it as I want to create a system wide singleton of the lowest layer...

What .Net technologies or patterns are best suited as a solution to this problem?

We are using .Net 4, WPF and C#.

EDIT: The communication with the USB-device requires a connection procedure that includes calibration of the hardware and that actually takes some time (seconds). So connecting and disconnecting for each call will not be an option. For performance issues I will need to connect once and then keep that connection open.

Comment: OK, so how do you access this USB device from C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at using a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).  Control access to the USB portion of the code so only one holder of the mutex can use it.

Comment: Yes, the module shared amongst instances should of course be thread safe. But I guess that I would be able to use a simple Lock() instead of a Mutex most of the time as the synchronization would take place inside the shared (single instance) module.

Comment: You are missing the point.  A lock is in-process, not visible outside of it.  A mutex can have a name, allowing other processes to access it. Note Mutex.OpenExisting(string) and the Mutext(bool, string, out bool) constructor.  You'll need an arbiter.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with my answer.  Like Hans says, a single named mutex can be accessed by multiple processes (as long as they know the name of the mutex to use).

Comment: Ok, yes now I see what you mean. That would have solved my problem if I could connect and disconnect to the USB-device for each call. Then I would have a global Mutex shared the by the different application instances that would ensure single use of the USB-device. Unfortunately I can't do that (see my edit of the first post). Good idea though!

Comment: Well, I could actually use a Mutex to ensure thread safe usage of the shared module closest to the USB-driver. But what technology (WCF, remoting, etc?) should I use for communication with that module?

Comment: You should not share the module at runtime. Instead you share the Mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Use exactly one process that accesses directly the USB device - this process could be for example a Windows Service. All applications talk to this single process, never directly to the USB device...

For communication with other processes you can any IPC technology although IF all your processes are on the same machine/system then I would recommend using a combination of a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) and [shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) (via [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx)) since that is the fastest IPC mechanism...

IF performance is not a big issue then use WCF because that gives you a nice interface and the ability to allow acccess via LAN if need should ever come up...

Comment: WCF communication with a Windows service was the first thing that came to my mind when we started talking about multiple instances of our application . But as I haven't worked with interprocess communication in .Net I felt unsure if there were better technologies available.

Comment: I see - "better is relative" in this case... there are several IPC mechanisms available like Pipes, Sockets (TCP/IP or UDP), like WCF (be it SOAP, REST or TCP), Windows messaging, Shared Memory etc. shared memory is by far the fastest although local to the machine... the other can implement IPC over a network (LAN/WAN)... what exactly do you mean by "better" ?